# Getting nil while accessing cell outside

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Below is my code, I am accessing `cell` in my function, but I am getting `nil`.

```
 private func setDataForStatusLabel(stausText: String, statusColor: UIColor) {

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CustomLocateVehicleCell

    if let cell = cell {
        cell.statusLabel.text = stausText
        cell.containerStatusLabel.text = stausText
        cell.statusLabel.textColor = statusColor
        cell.containerStatusLabel.textColor = statusColor
        cell.statusColorView.backgroundColor = statusColor
        cell.containerStatusColorView.backgroundColor = statusColor

    }
}
```

Comment: you can only get cell which is visible on screen.

Comment: 1. Is cell visible on the screen? 2. Is the cell of type `CustomLocateVehicleCell`?

Comment: @ozgur 1.yes 2.yes

Comment: its your cell of `CustomLocateVehicleCell` type class?

Comment: @ReinierMelian yes

Comment: this method is called after the tableView reload?

Comment: calling here override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}

Comment: You might want to add your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation. That'll help

Comment: Don't manipulate the **view** (the cell) directly. Update the **model**  (the data source array) and call `reloadData` or `reloadRows(at:with:`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the issue by passing `cell` parameter

```
private func setDataForStatusLabel(stausText: String, statusColor: UIColor, cell: CustomLocateVehicleCell) {

    cell.statusLabel.text = stausText
    cell.containerStatusLabel.text = stausText
    cell.statusLabel.textColor = statusColor
    cell.containerStatusLabel.textColor = statusColor
    cell.statusColorView.backgroundColor = statusColor
    cell.containerStatusColorView.backgroundColor = statusColor

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use dequeueReusableCell

```
let cell = tblView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomLocateVehicleCell") as! CustomLocateVehicleCell
cell.configureCell(stausText, statusColor)
```

1. But before this make sure UITableViewCell is dragged and dropped on UITableView
2. change the class of cell with CustomLocateVehicleCell
3. set Identifier CustomLocateVehicleCell
4. configureCell create this method in CustomLocateVehicleCell and write your code where to managed cell's colour and text